# "bazel aquery" returns no action information for java_proto_library

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm looking to use `bazel aquery` to explore inputs and outputs for targets, and have found that `java_proto_library` produces no output.

For a simple example:

```
proto_library(
    name = "example_proto",
    srcs = ["example.proto"],
)

java_proto_library(
    name = "example_java_proto",
    deps = [":example_proto"],
)
```

`bazel aquery //:example_proto` returns the action information as expected, but `bazel aquery //:example_java_proto` returns only INFO logging:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //:example_java_proto (0 packages loaded, 15 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.151s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 0 total actions
```

Full example code at https://github.com/theothertomelliott/bazel-issues/tree/java_proto_aquery

Is this a particular quirk of `java_proto_library` (I've seen issues raised about src jars and other oddities of this rule), a bug, or something I'm missing in the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the implementation details of `java_proto_library`, and because of how the build graph is built and how the query functions query it.

`java_proto_library` doesn't actually register any actions itself: [JavaProtoLibrary.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/d7c1cefc8c082fd7119470436f366c618d1eea06/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/java/proto/JavaProtoLibrary.java). Instead, it run an aspect over all its deps: [BazelJavaProtoLibraryRule.java#L49-L52](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/74d84d43b0b810e7eb2c8f866694fa2dcf209baa/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/java/proto/BazelJavaProtoLibraryRule.java#L49-L52). That aspect is then evaluated on all the proto dependencies of the `java_proto_library`, and registers the java proto actions with the proto dependencies: [JavaProtoAspect.java#L206](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/b23e8018da6ebabbe00ad415f3bc879dbeb6e6c4/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/java/proto/JavaProtoAspect.java#L206)

So `bazel aquery //:example_java_proto` is correct in that that target really has no actions. But `bazel aquery //:example_proto` also doesn't return java proto actions. The first thing that's needed is [`--include_aspects`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/aquery.html#include_aspects-default-false), so that aquery outputs information from any aspects attached to the targets.

The 2nd thing is the state of the build graph when `aquery` is run:

```
$ bazel clean
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.

$ bazel aquery //:example_proto --include_aspects 2>/dev/null | grep action
action 'Generating Descriptor Set proto_library //:example_proto'

$ bazel aquery //:example_java_proto --include_aspects 2>/dev/null | grep action

(nothing)

$ bazel aquery //:example_proto --include_aspects 2>/dev/null | grep action
action 'Generating Descriptor Set proto_library //:example_proto'
action 'Generating Java (Immutable) proto_library //:example_proto'
action 'Building libexample_proto-speed.jar (1 source jar)'
action 'Compiling Java headers libexample_proto-speed-hjar.jar (1 source jar)'
```

So when `example_proto` is first queried, it returns 1 action, then `example_java_proto` is queried, and it returns nothing, then `example_proto` is queried again, and it returns 4 actions: the one from before, and some java ones. This is because when `example_java_proto` is analyzed, the aspect it registers runs and the graph now contains the actions from the aspect.

This is basically by design, because Bazel doesn't look at anything beyond what it's asked to query or build. If there were a `cc_proto_library` in some package somewhere, Bazel won't know about it until it's asked to load or analyze that package. Aspects can come from anywhere, so in order to get complete information, Bazel would have to load every BUILD file in the repository, which won't scale for large repositories.

The `rdeps` query function can be used to get everything:

```
$ bazel clean
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.

$ bazel cquery "rdeps(//:example_proto, ...)"
INFO: Analyzed 3 targets (20 packages loaded, 908 targets configured).
INFO: Found 3 targets...
//:example_proto (45d0b89373a0dfd75ac4b432cf2b12138c1203b34bdec57557dfef52e7a6ed03)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.408s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 0 total actions

$ bazel aquery //:example_proto --include_aspects 2>/dev/null | grep action
action 'Generating Descriptor Set proto_library //:example_proto'
action 'Generating Java (Immutable) proto_library //:example_proto'
action 'Building libexample_proto-speed.jar (1 source jar)'
action 'Compiling Java headers libexample_proto-speed-hjar.jar (1 source jar)'
```

`rdeps(//:example_proto, //...)` will find all the reverse dependencies of `example_proto`, and the `//...` loads the entire repository. Note that `cquery` is needed here, rather than `query`, because `query` doesn't run the analysis phase, where actions are created, whereas `cquery` does run the analysis phase.

Answer (score 1):

java rules is a [built-in bazel rule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/74d84d43b0b810e7eb2c8f866694fa2dcf209baa/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/java/proto/JavaProtoLibrary.java), and its implementation is based on [aspects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html),
so if you first run

```
bazel build --nobuild //:example_java_proto
```

and then

```
bazel aquery '//:example_proto' --include_aspects=true
```

you should see an action graph, enriched with java specific actions